# controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found a problem in check angular JS
the problem is when you click on a link that Normally it directed to any page he goes to an error page seveur
here is my code, help me please and thank you in advance

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"

></script>


  <script >

    var app = angular.module('app' , ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

          .when('/',{templateUrl: 'test/home.html'})
          .when('/comments',{templateUrl: 'test/comments.html'})
          .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});
    });

    app.controller('MedCtrl',function($scope) {
      console .log($scope);
      $scope.mdd = [ 
      {
        "username": "<ReferenceEr ror: firstname is not defined>",
        "content": "Incididunt quis culpa quis aliquip excepteur commodo proident non amet ea ex excepteur elit."
      },
      {
        "username": "<ReferenceError: firstname is not defined>",
        "content": "Excepteur irure enim est qui mollit laboris occaecat nostrud occaecat ullamco consequat."
      },
      {
        "username": "<ReferenceError: firstname is not defined>",
        "content": "In commodo enim labore dolor occaecat est nisi laborum velit anim reprehenderit labore sint cupidatat."
      },
      {
        "username": "<ReferenceError: firstname is not defined>",
        "content": "Excepteur elit officia nulla consectetur velit qui laborum ea mollit consequat deserunt excepteur."
      },
      {
        "username": "<ReferenceError: firstname is not defined>",
        "content": "Culpa enim nisi officia cupidatat velit laboris id veniam."
      },
      {
        "username": "<ReferenceError: firstname is not defined>",
        "content": "Labore elit excepteur tempor magna culpa est magna ea est sit dolor ad."
      },
      {
        "username": "<ReferenceError: firstname is not defined>",
        "content": "Ut esse pariatur amet ullamco aute fugiat aliqua excepteur amet mollit."
      }];
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
  <h1>Article #1</h1>

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <h2>3 Commentaire</h2>

    <a href="#/comments">Voir les commentaires</a>
```

comments.html

```
 <div ng-controller="MedCtrl" ng-init="test1='med'">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test1">
            <br> {{ test1 }}
        <div ng-repeat="md in mdd | filter: {username:test1} ">
            <p>{{ md.username }} <br> {{ md.content }}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: there's lots of typos in your question and in the code, I would suggest using longer variable names instead of things like `med` and `mdd` and `md`, your fellow developers will thank you for it.

Comment: And also indent your code, really hard to read it like this.

Comment: Give `controller name` to `$routeProvider` along with the `templateURL` that you have given. That might solve your issue,